# I am unable to echo the ssh which i looge in using bash script

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'please enter the ssh server name: ' ssh_name
ssh ${ssh_name} 'bash' <<'EOF'
echo ${ssh_name}
exit
EOF
```

Comment: What happens when you run it, and what did you expect/hope to have happen?  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a guide on how to ask clear, answerable questions

Comment: upon compiling i was expecting to display the ssh_server name i have entered during read -p prompt but it throws empty output

Comment: Information in comments is easy to miss, and comments usually do not format correctly.  Instead please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44762294/edit) the question with updated information

Comment: Sorry about that Eric

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm just trying to help you get help more effectively

Answer (score 1):

Because you put single quotes around your heredoc limit string it does not expand the variables in place, so it tries to do the variable expansion on the server side, where that variable is not set.

If you want to have the variables expanded locally, just do not use the single quotes around `EOF`:

```
read -p 'please enter the ssh server name: ' ssh_name
ssh ${ssh_name} 'bash' <<EOF
echo ${ssh_name}
exit
EOF
```

This will expand `ssh_name` on the local side then `echo` will see the already expanded string on the remote end and `echo` it.

If you want to pass that variable to the other side, you could make it part of the command you're executing:

```
read -p 'please enter the ssh server name: ' ssh_name
ssh ${ssh_name} remote_name="$ssh_name" 'bash' <<'EOF'
echo ${remote_name}
exit
EOF
```

(though you do not have to change the name of the variable, I just did that to highlight that it's available on the remote side).

[here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput?#Heredocs_And_Herestrings) is some good reading about heredocs and herestrings.

Answer (score 0):

Becuase $ssh_name is set in the shell you are calling ssh from, and you are trying to echo $ssh_name from within the ssh session itself, where it is not set.

If you move the echo statement to after the EOF or before the ssh statement, then you will find that it works just fine.

Comment: That's perfect .. Anyways of calling it after i do ssh ...?